# How to return a number of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a function which receives an array of person objects. The function should return the number of persons who lives in the city of Syndey. But,  I am getting problem in returning a number of the person who lives in Sydney. What should I do? Anyone can help me, please?

This is the code that I have created:

```
function numberOfPeopleInSydney(person) {

   people.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
    if(arrayItem.lives.city==="Sydney")

        return arrayItem.name;
});

}
```

Comment: It might not matter too much but you've spelled _Sydney_ wrong pretty much everywhere.

Comment: `forEach` is a wrong choice, this `return` does nothing. And `tallyPeopleInSyndey` misses `return` statement

Comment: You even get `person` but call `forEach` on `people`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forEach` just calls the function you pass it with every element of the array but doesn't use the returned values.

If you want to keep count of the people who pass your condition, you'll have to increment some kind of counter in the if-block, also fix the argument name and add a return in the actual function, like barbsan mentioned:

```js
function tallyPeopleInSyndey(people) {
    var count = 0
    people.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
        if(arrayItem.lives.city==="Syndey")
            count++
    })
    return count
}
```

Personally, I'd just filter `people` by the condition and get the length of the resulting array:

```js
people.filter(function(person) {
    return person.lives.city === "Syndey"
}).length
```